# How to position popup at top of screen or fixed at top in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, popup

I have a popup in jquery mobile

```
<div data-role="popup"   id="itemDetails">
...
</div>
```

and I call programmatically to open with:

`$('#itemDetails').popup('open');`

, but always open centered in `x,y` on screen, and I want show fix to top `(y=0)` of screen, and fixed when I have scroll.

How I can do it?, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set the top property in css to 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like CSS should be enough:

```
#itemDetails{
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
}
```

If you really want to use jQuery, then

```
$('#itemDetails').css({position:'fixed',top:'0'});
```

Comment: Finally your solution help me fine, but then I have used popup options: `$('#itemDetails').popup('open',{y:0})` works fine too.

Comment: And I put in AndroidManifest.xml: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` , and with it, don't happend strange things, positioning popup's

Comment: Ok, I'm not familiar with Android but looks like you've got it to work; congrats!

Answer (score 1):

The solution did not work for me.  Putting the css in the .css file did not take effect.  I found that I needed to use the second type with:

```
$("#popupBasic").popup('open');
$('#popupBasic').css({position:'fixed',top:'10px',left:'30px','display':'block'});
```

then to close the popup:

```
$('#popupBasic').popup('close');
$('#popupBasic').css({display:'none'});
```