# Fix Pop like Bootstrap in Jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am implementing a mobile website then i am using Jquery mobile pop up, But when i scrolled the page then pop up also scrolled and not visible. So i want to fix pop up in jquery mobile. I have seen one link : [How to position popup at top of screen or fixed at top in jquery mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130420/how-to-position-popup-at-top-of-screen-or-fixed-at-top-in-jquery-mobile)

CODE:

```
<a href="#popupMenu1" data-icon="user" data-rel="popup"  data-transition="slideup">My Winni</a> 



<div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu1" data-theme="a"> 
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"> 
            <li data-role="list-divider">Choose an action</li> 
            <li><a data-ajax="false" href="<c:url value="/my-winni/orders"/>" data-ajax="false">Orders</a></li> 
            <li><a data-ajax="false" href="<c:url value="/my-winni/wallet"/>" data-ajax="false">My Wallet</a></li> 
            <li><a data-ajax="false" href="<c:url value="/my-winni/saved-address"/>" data-ajax="false">Address Book</a></li> 
            <li><a data-ajax="false" href="<c:url value="/my-winni/referrals"/>" data-ajax="false">Invite To Friends</a></li> 
            <li><a data-ajax="false" href="<c:url value="/my-winni/captured-moment/albums"/>">Captured Moments</a></li>
        </ul> [![enter image description here][1]][1]
    </div>
```

[image]

can we implement like bootstrap pop up in jquery mobile?

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp